# passing main argument to method

Tags: java, arrays, string, program-entry-point

I'm trying to pass the array of strings argument from the main into my `integerCheck` method. The input to the main will never be more than 3 strings long. The code compiles fine, but when I try to enter an input of 3 strings I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

Where is this coming from?

```
private static void integerCheck(String[] b)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    { 
        try {Integer.parseInt(b[i]);}
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        { 
        System.err.println("one of inputs not an int");
        System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    integerCheck(args);
}
```

Comment: Think about how many times the loop will run if you pass just 3 arguments.

Comment: `i` will have the values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` in your loop. An array with three elements will have the indices `0`, `1`, `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be: `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` (If you pass `4` elements to your program, it should work with `4`, but if you want only `3` inputs, it should be `3`).

**Why?**

Because `for(i=0;i<4;i++)` is running on `0 1 2 3`. So the length of the expected input is actually `4`. So you're trying to reach `b[3]`, and this is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

*Note*: A debugger would help you a lot.. use it and you'll better understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple mistake. If you have 3 elements in the array they are indexed 0, 1 and 2. Your loop goes from 0 to less than 4, which means it tried to access elements 0, 1, 2 and 3. Element 3 does not exist, since you only gave 3 arguments. Another way to think about it is that element number 3 is the fourth element in the array (because the elements are numbered starting from 0)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for(i=0;i<4;i++)` has more elements than `string[b]`

try this and replace

```
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
```

with

```
 for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
 private static void integerCheck(String[] b)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        { 
            try {Integer.parseInt(b[i]);}
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            { 
            System.err.println("one of inputs not an int");
            System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     if(args.length==3)
    {
    integerCheck(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is compiling fine because there is no syntactical error in the code you have written.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  is a run time exception , which is encountered when you are trying to access an index which is out of the size of the array.

In the current situation you will face this whenever you pass less than 4 Argumnents while invoking the main method.
Remember Indices in java are 0 based, so you have 0 1 2 and 3 .

As per your statement you said, u are passing 3 args, which are located at 0 1 and 2 respectively, so either pass a 4th value or change your condition to for(i=0;i<2;i++).